# CSS padding issue, padding not working

Tags: html, css, padding

Im trying to use padding to push an image 18px from the top of a div. Neither margin or padding are working, and after comparing the two padding seems to be what I want anyway.

The problem is with the `footer-middle-left-left-image` div tag. The margin on the text one works fine though.

---

Here's the html:

```html
<div id = "footer-middle-left-left">
     <div id = "footer-middle-left-left-picture">
          <img src = "" alt = "some_text">
     </div>
     <div id = "footer-middle-left-left-text">
          If you would like to join our newsletter, please enter your </br>
          email address below.
     </div>
     <div id = "footer-middle-left-left-email">
     </div>
</div>
```

The CSS I have is:

```css
#footer-middle-left-left {
    float: left;
    width: 483px;
    height: 175px;
}

#footer-middle-left-left-image {
    float: left;
    width: 483px;
    height: 59px;
    padding-top: 18px;
}

#footer-middle-left-left-text {
    width: 483px;
    height: 58px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    color: white;
}

#footer-middle-left-left-email {
    height: 58px;
    float: left;
    width: 483px;
}
```

---

Any help would be appreciated! Also any advice, anything at all would be nice too. I'm pretty new so advice not relevant to my problem is also appreciated, like is this a good id-naming convention, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html you have `footer-middle-left-left-picture` but in css `#footer-middle-left-left-image`
Is it this bug or you just make mistake on paste code?

http://jsfiddle.net/CmwHu/

Comment: That was the issue, I was looking at the code for too long I guess and didn't see the simple answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: This is the worst type of problem :)

Comment: Another problem with the padding-top is it also seems to add padding to the bottom, even if I set padding-bottom to 0px, it's still there? This is making the div 18px bigger than it should be and thus, pushing the div below it down.

Comment: Try remove height from text text element. This is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/CmwHu/2/ ?

Comment: That's still not working for me, the image I have is 35px tall, so with the 18px padding, I need the image div's height to be 53 px. Then, the image should be at the bottom of the div, and the text display right under it, but it's getting 18px extra on the bottom somehow when I use padding-top. :(

Comment: this is the file for the image https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tbqyh5uff9lsfj/joinnewslettertitle.png

Comment: So you need to set text position exactly under image? Remember div real height is calculate by add height and padding.

Comment: Shorter id names would probably make it easier to spot errors like that ;-)

Comment: So if the image is 35px I should add padding 18px and have the height of the div as 35px?

Comment: Look here how height is calculating: http://jsfiddle.net/genua/ As you can see on #div2 I add padding and the height of this div automaticaly increase.

Answer (score 1):

`#footer-middle-left-left-image` this id doesnt exist in your html.

So i have changed `footer-middle-left-left-picture` to `#footer-middle-left-left-image`. 
It is working now

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w7fBR/)**

Comment: Ah, that's the issue, thanks! Ive been looking at the code for too long!